# MongoDB multiple queries at once

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "Registration State" : "NY",
    "Issue Date" : ISODate("2019-12-27T18:30:00Z"),

}
{
    "Registration State" : "NJ",
    "Issue Date" : ISODate("2019-06-19T18:30:00Z"),

}
```

I'm very new to MongoDB. Working with a dataset that requires me to find out the number of states for which tickets have been filed for year 2019, also provide the list of the states.

PS- this is a very trimmed version of the dataset for convenience.

Comment: You could use the [MongoDb Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) along with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation)

Comment: Yes, I am kind of finding it hard to put it in code. I have the basic algorithm, but finding it difficult to put it in correct syntax/function calls.

Comment: Add some code of what you have tried so far. So, we can help you better.

Comment: Well, this is horrific code.Both of them failed.
db.test.find({$expr:{$eq:[{$year:"$Issue Date"},2020]}}).distinct("Registration State").length;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this find expression:

```
db.collection.find(
   {
      $and: [
         { "Issue Date": { $gte: new Date("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") } },
         { "Issue Date": { $lt: new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") } }
      ]
   }
).count()
```

Or as aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { year: { $year: "$Issue Date" } } },
   { $match: { "year": 2019 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Yes, this gives me data count for the year 2019. But I wanted the number of states for which tickets have been filed for year 2019.

Comment: Then replace `_id: null,` by `_id: "$Registration State",`

Answer (score 0):

a little modification based on the above answer

to get the different states

```
let resultArray= db.collection.distinct("Registration State", 
   {
      $and: [
         { "Issue Date": { $gte: new Date("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") } },
         { "Issue Date": { $lt: new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") } }
      ]
   }
)
```

to get length

```
resultArray.length
```